# SKProduct returned via productsRequest:didReceiveResponse does not have .introductoryPrice in production, but sandbox is as expected

Tags: storekit, skproduct

We have an IAP setup with a free trial. In sandbox, we see the expected trial period for this product ID.
In production (and when I build locally using Release config), .introductoryPrice for the same identifier is nil.
I have verified that the IAP is setup in AppStore. This is a product ID that's been around for quite some time,
I believe the only recent change was editing the Subscription Group it belongs to but no edits to the IAP itself.

Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

In-App product should be processed **separately** with application in production after AppStore review.

If you change or edit IAP product settings, **it may take up to 24 hours of processing time.**

So I believe your IAP product have a introductory price Now because 3 days passed.